# Which test should be used to find the probability of greater or equal to a mean?

Tags: t-test, survey

I have a result of survey about the satisfaction of regulation changes. My hypothesis is the new regulation provided more satisfaction compared to the old one, which test should i use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical tests have the option of being interpreted as one-tailed, or two-tailed. The two-tailed tests have twice the probability of the one-tailed tests. The one-tailed tests for location (e.g., for mean, median etc.) can be chosen as asking for locations $A$ or $B$ if $A\leq B$, or $A\geq B$, such that the resulting separate probabilities $p_1$ and $p_2$ are related as $p_1(A\geq B)=1-p_2(A\leq B)$. Now typically $p_1\neq p_2$, and it is the lesser of these that is one-half the probability of the two-tailed test. The two-tailed test asks if $A=B$, and if significant (e.g., has $p<0.05$) then $A=B$ is rejected as unlikely. For whatever software you are using, just check whether $A>B$  numerically or the obverse. If $A>B$ numerically, then 1/2 the two-tailed probability of that is $p(B\leq A)$.